# `go mod tidy` fails to download private GitHub repository

Tags: git, go, go-modules

Here is the response

```
not found: github.com/me/private-repo@v0.0.0-20220413034319-81fe8421f99f: invalid version: git ls-remote -q origin in /tmp/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/ea2baff0eaed39430ee011ad9a011101f13b668d5fcbd9dffdfa1e0a45422b40: exit status 128:
    fatal: could not read Username for 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled
Confirm the import path was entered correctly.
If this is a private repository, see https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.
```

I have tried to add a record in `~/.netrc` with password of a freshly created GitHub Personal access token and add config in `~/.gitconfig`

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

All these are not working.

If I disable the sum checking by `GOSUMDB=off go mod tidy` then it works yet I don't think this is correct to me.

Comment: Any progress on this one? I start suspecting it's a github bug.
For me only one repo doesn't work like that, all other repos work fine.

Answer (score 5):

As your error says

> could not read Username

So, you should change the `~/.gitconfig`:

change this:

```
[url "ssh://git@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

to this:

```
[url "https://{{username}}:{{access_toke}}@github.com"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com
```

also, you need the `~/.netrc` file, with the content like this:

```
machine github.com login {{username}} password {{access_token}}
```

**P.S:**
You should be aware that your private repository should be in your `GOPRIVATE=__YOUR_DOMAIN__`

Comment: In case the private repo belongs to an organization, you use a more specific url rewrite for the org only 
```[url "https://{{username}}:{{access_toke}}@github.com/org"] insteadOf = https://github.com/org```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend:

```
[url "https://YourUsername@github.com/"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
```

That way, any HTTPS URL will use your username.

And with a [Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (cross-platform), you can cache your [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.4/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) in a secure encrypted local vault.