# golang module imports from keybase repo or locally

Tags: go

I know it must be a very basic question, but i don't seem to be able to get around it for a while :D

So, my git repo is on keybase.
normally external or local imports are looking like `"github.com/streadway/amqp"`
How can a import a module from keybase git repo?
Or, how do i import it as local module? The absolute path is `/Users/****/go/src/api`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly You have 2 questions, the first one is you are looking to add a package from a private repository. the second is you want to use a package from another path.

- for question one, you can see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71853092/3415984) and change it for your keybase
- for the second one, you can add replace in your `go.mod` file.

like this:

```
replace (
    the/package/address => ../../****/path/to/package
)
```

notice: the replace path should be routed from your `go.mod` file.