# Go mod tidy fails on private repository when git clone works

Tags: git, go

I put my ssh key in github so `git clone` works for a certain private repository; yet `go mod tidy` fails when trying to access the same repository, with the error message shown below. I could use help troubleshooting this problem. The error message from `go mod tidy` (redacting the name of the private repository, but otherwise verbatim) is:

```
    github.com/[private repository path]: cannot find module providing package github.com/[private repository path]: module github.com/[private repository path]: git ls-remote -q origin in /mnt/dependencies/gopath/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/a1f499df6a9855aecdc77bda31504008583a3268fdd403799aade71bb47df7d2: exit status 128:
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

The successful git clone command (again redacting the private repository) is:

```
git clone git@github.com:[private repository path].git
```

My `.gitconfig` file is (with my name and email redacted):

```
[user]
    name = [my name]
    email = [my email]
[url "github.com:"]
    insteadOf = https://github.com/
[core]
    excludesfile = /workdir/.gitignore
```

Other things that might make a difference:

- I am running commands as root in a Docker container.
- I tried to run `go mod tidy` on my host with the same key in `~/.ssh` as I have on the Docker container, and I got login prompts, which github no longer supports (they want SSH keys or personal access tokens).
- The email in my gitconfig matches email given in the public key that I put on github.com.

A second, related question: Does the fact that I can run `git clone` rule out keys being uploaded wrong to github, and forgetting to enable SSO for the key on github?

Here is a similar question but it involves personal access tokens rather than ssh keys: [`go mod tidy` fails to download private GitHub repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71851732/go-mod-tidy-fails-to-download-private-github-repository)

Comment: What is your directory structure? Are you in the same directory when you run `git pull` and when you run `go mod tidy`?

Comment: My mistake for saying `git pull` when it was actually `git clone`. For those that read Code Apprentice's comment later on, I really did say `git pull` in one place where it's corrected now to say `git clone`. A direct answer to the question of where that command was run is that I was in a temporary directory when I ran `git clone`.

Comment: Anyone with enough reputation points can view the edit history and see your changes. Still, you didn't address the core part of my comment...what is the directory structure and what directory do you run the commands in?

Comment: I can't answer exact directories for privacy reasons. But I can add a little more detail. Relative to `~/Documents` on the Windows host, I ran `go mod tidy` from `[redacted A]/[redacted B]`. This is the root of the clone of repository that needs `[private repository]`. I ran the other command -- `git clone git@github.com:[private repository path].git` -- from `[redacted A]/tmp`.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you did something like this then: `cd a/tmp` and then `git clone git@github.com:my_repo.git`. This will create a directory `a/tmp/my_repo`. Then did you `cd ../b` before running `go mod tidy`? If so why would you expect this to know about the repo at `a/tmp/my_repo`?

Comment: Side note: it is common to use placeholders like this. Note how I use syntax that would be fine from the command line. Adding the `[]` just adds extra noise. Even made up names give us something concrete to talk about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I am running commands as root in a Docker container.

Make sure then it does access the same keys (in `/root/.ssh`) as the ones you are using with your regular account.

And check if the Git global config settings actually include your `insteadOf` directive.

> tried to run go mod tidy on my host with the same key in `~/.ssh` as I have on the Docker container, and I got login prompts.

That means the public key is not properly registered to the GitHub user profile, or said user does not have the right to access the repository.

Comment: Re: "or said user does not have the right to access the repository". The user given by the email address in the public key is the same on the Docker container and the host. Does the OS user matter in this context? The OS user differs between the host and the container.

Comment: @Predrag3141: a public key doesn't have an email address. If you are referring to the `user.name@example.com` that you find in the `.pub` *file*, that's just a comment. The way GitHub decides who you are is by looking at the public key string (the part after the type and before the email-comment, in the `.pub` file) and seeing who registered that public key with GitHub. They then challenge the ssh providing that public key to decrypt something, which requires the corresponding private key; if that ssh can decrypt it, the holder of the public key has the private key too (= allowed).

Comment: Meanwhile, if you're referring to the Git `user.email` setting, ssh doesn't even *see* that one at all, much less provide it to GitHub.

Comment: I was referring to the email in the public key.

Comment: @Predrag3141 An [SSH public key format](https://www.openssh.org/txt/draft-ietf-secsh-publickeyfile-02.txt) includes a comment after a space placeholder ` `. That comment can be [*anything* you like](https://serverfault.com/a/442935/783), including an email address. See example in "[What significance does the user/host at the end of an SSH public key file hold?](https://serverfault.com/a/743551/783)"

Comment: @Predrag3141 That comment in the public SSH key, like an email address, has nothing to do with how GitHub authenticates you.

Answer (score 3):

I found the answer to my problem, but it turns on a fact that I omitted in the question.

I didn't realize until the next morning that my Docker image had a higher version of golang than was used to populate `$GOPATH` (or at least I didn't realize how important this was). To fix this, I deleted everything under `$GOPATH` and re-ran `go mod tidy` with no issues.

The checklist in VonC's answer is useful and more to the point of the question as stated, so I accepted it. But I'll add to it for anyone that comes across this post:

"Is the version of golang used for `go mod tidy` different from what populated `$GOPATH`?"

Comment: Also, what an unhelpful error message "'origin' does not appear to be a git repository" was!

Comment: Oh my God thank you so much! I have spent hours trying to solve this, I was so sure everything is correct and yet it doesn't work still until I remove everything under $GOPATH.